# calling a function using a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a variable I stored a function name, but when I try to call it from a sub() I've got some errors "Type mismatch", maybe I'm doing it wrong.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim list As Collection
    Dim functionName As String
    
    functionName = "asBuiltComplete()"
    Set list = functionName
    For Each rs In list
        Debug.Print rs.getId & " " & rs.getActualDate & " " & rs.getBlDate
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try playing around with `Eval()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Application.Run`:

```
functionName = "asBuiltComplete"
Set list = Application.Run(functionName)
```

While you could use `Eval`, `Application.Run` is somewhat more limited in functionality so has less chance of weirdness.

However, this is bad code. You generally want to avoid dynamic function names whenever feasible, and just call the function.